# How do I pass private MP4 URLs from Google Cloud Storage to my ChromeCast? (chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo)

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, chromecast

I am trying to access my media from my Google Cloud Storage with an access token. I am able to use the URL: `https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/*bucket*/o/*path*/index.mp4?alt=media` with an Authorization Header and my access token to download the files locally.

My problem is that I am not sure how to give those same permissions to my Chromecast to cast my media for me. I tried appending the access token to the URL like so: `https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/*bucket*/o/*path*/index.mp4?alt=media&access_token=*access_token*`, but just ended up with this error:

[image]

I can mark this question as answered if I could figure out how to do any of the following things:

1. Format/sign my URL that would allow me to access my Google Cloud resources without having to set the authorization header.
2. Format the headers when the MP4 URL is added to the chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo function (setting the headers when casting the MP4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with the Chromecast API and its capabilities, but I do know how to avoid the problem.

Google Cloud Storage (GCS) allows you to generate temporarily-valid URLs which can be used without any separate auth mechanisms, called "signed URLs." The idea is that you take a URL which would download an object, tack on an expiration date, and then sign the whole thing with the private key of a service account which has permission to download the object. You then give the URL to a user (in this case, Chromecast), which can then act as the service account to download the object. It sounds like this might work well for your use case.

The Google Cloud client libraries for several languages can sign URLs. Take a look here for details: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks for the help!